# Переход между страничками на сайте

Tags: html, url

Я только не давно начал вливаться в сферу веб разработки, вот стoлкнулся с таким нюансом.
В большинстве современных сайтов присутствует деление на различные страницы
Что-то типо
"vk.com/im" "vk.com/username"

Вот я хочу сделать переход по разным страничкам на сайте. Пишу ссылку с использованием тега `<a href = ''></a>`
Однако при переходe на новую вкладку в url появляется .html
Сайт уже стоит на домене, и выглядит это как-то так
"Name.com/2page.html"
Как это убрать?
Заранeе спасибо за советы

Comment: Не понятно. Покажите пример, какое значение в `href` приводит к какому результирующему урлу. Также имеет значение исходный урл с которого Вы переходите. Его тоже укажите в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется маршрутизацией.

`.html` появляется потому что вы переходите конкретно в файл. Сделать так, как вы хотите, можно:

1. Отправляя данные с сервера:

`node.js/express`:

```js
app.get('/путь_через_слеш_тот_который_вы_хотите', {
    // Выдаёте нужную информацию
});
```

2. Маршрутизация на клиенте:

`js/react`:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/ваш_кастомный_путь">
            <Ваша_компонента />
            // Здесь вы выдаёте какие-либо данные
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

В обоих примерах вы по-сути делаете запрос на определенный путь и по этому пути приложение вам что-либо выдаёт.

Полезные ссылки:

[express](https://expressjs.com/ru/)

[react](https://ru.reactjs.org/)

[Маршрутизация express](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html)

[Маршрутизация react](https://learn-reactjs.ru/training-project/routing)